# Should I go with web3.py or web3.js as a beginner to start with dapp development?

Tags: web3js, dapps, web3.py

I already have foundation in JavaScript and have done web app in HTML, CSS, Js and Django for a bit, and I am looking forward to learn about Dapp.

Initially I want to go with web3.py but after looking at the Youtube videos and number of stackexchange questions  answered for web3.py are much less than the web3.js

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3.py (526 questions)
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3.js (4,847 questions)

It seems that web3.js is much more supported? What are your opinions?

Comment: You've already worked with JS, saw that web.js is more supported than web3.py and still want to go with web3.py? x) On a more serious note, i've never used web3.py so idrk how to answer you, but there should be nothing that you can do with web3.py that you cant do with web3.js

Comment: Here is a discussion on this specific topic: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87963/which-ethereum-framework-to-choose-truffle-vs-brownie/103176#103176 - Brownie / Python ecosystem is objectively more productive if you are free to choose between JavaScript and Python.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks that's very helpful